# Perl: Return ALL instances of regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am using curl to store a website as a variable, $mystring. How would I return every single 8-digit number that starts with "810"?

I currently have:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
my $curl = `curl ...`;
$curl =~ /(810\d+)/;
print "$1\n";
```

Except this only returns the first instance. How would I return ALL instances and store it in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the global modifier, `/g`, to capture all the matches.

To search for 8-digit numbers starting with 810, use `\b` to match word boundaries, and specify the number of digits to search for using braces; `\d{5}` matches 5 digits.

To store the matches in an array, you can do the following:

```
my @numbers = ($curl =~ /\b810\d{5}\b/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`/g` Modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers).

Note, if you're not a regex expert, one potential solution is to pull out all numbers, and then filter out the ones that you don't want like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $curl = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my @nums = grep {length == 8 && /^810/} $curl =~ /\d+/g;

print $_, "\n" for @nums;

__DATA__
Hello world
1                               # Too_short
134                             # Too_short
123456789                       # Too_long
81012345 810123456 81011111     # Pass    Too_long     Pass
81098765 81098765 181098765     # Pass    Test_repeat  Too_long_with_substring
```

Outputs:

```
81012345
81011111
81098765
81098765
```

However, the same can be accomplished in a single regex of course:

```
my @nums = $curl =~ /(?<!\d)(810\d{5})(?!\d)/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `/g` modifier in a `while` loop:

```
my @numbers;
while ($curl =~ /(810\d{5})/g) {
    push @numbers, $1;
}
print "@numbers\n";
```

To find 8-digit numbers, search for 5 digits after the prefix. Moreover, if you don't want to match parts of larger numbers, check for word boundaries (`\b`) or look ahead and behind for non-numbers.